# how to query documents in mongo that have nested objects and the object name is not static

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a4fbc1ea89167f338dea69"),
    "tname" : "ago",
    "status" : false,
    "customized" : true,
    "server-ago-net" : {
        "pps" : {
            "arc" : {
                "pps_name" : "pps one",
                "pps_status" : "="
            },
            "arc2" : {
                "pps_name" : "pps two",
                "pps_status" : "="
                "customized_files" : [ 
                    "/usr/share/asdf.txt"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
   "server2-ago-net" : {
        "pps" : {
           "pps1":{
                "pps_name" : "another pps file",
                "pps_status" : "="
            }           
            "pps2" : {
                "pps_name" : "the last pps file",
                "pps_status" : "="
                "customized_files" : [ 
                    "/usr/share/1234.txt"
                ]
        }
    }      
}
```

I need a query that will find all documents that have a "customized_files" section that has items in it, and return to me the server name, and package name.

So for the above example, I would want back the follow two records:

```
server-ago-net, "pps one", "/usr/share/asdf.txt"
server2-ago-net, "the last pps file", "/usr/share/1234.txt"
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. 
Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks!  it is a duplicate.  I guess my search key words were not the best, because i couldn't find that article.  What should I do with this question?  Just delete it?  is that the protocol? thanks!!

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate. Whether you delete it or not is up to you; either way is fine.